# “Should already have” or “should have already”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, word-order

> I think this new law is great and should already have exist earlier.

This sentence doesn’t seem correct to me. I don't know what, but something is disturbing me. Is it the tense of some verb? Or a false construction?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there is a tense problem. "Should already have exist" should be "should already have exist**ed**." This is the [past progressive](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-continuous-tense/) (or past continuous) tense combined with a modal verb "should." The auxiliary "have" cannot be combined with the present tense form of a verb: it always takes a past participle.

A more idiomatic way to say the same thing is:

> I think this new law is great and **should have been passed** earlier!

But the original version is grammatical when "exist" is corrected to "existed."

Comment: No, that's not progressive; it's perfect. Progressive uses _be_ as an auxilary and follows it with an _-ing_ verb form. Perfect uses _have_ as an auxiliary and follows it with a past participle form.